# How to get record between two hours in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, fetchxml

I want to get report per hour in SSRS Report.
like records created in 9:00 am to 10:00 am how I do that.

Comment: Be more speficic please

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two input parameters, startTime and lastTime, from double click to the report -> parameters-> add Parameters  than add a filter to the table, with 2 element:

```
time > startTime && time< endTime
```